# Monotouch dimensions not making sense

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have the following in my AppDelegate:

```
        const string fileName = "Content/tandc.html";
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var webView = new UIWebView(new RectangleF(0,-20, 300, 300));
        string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localHtmlUrl, false)));
        webView.ScalesPageToFit = false;
        webView.Opaque = false;
        webView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        var webelement = new UIViewElement("", webView, true);

        var agree = new StyledStringElement("Agree", () => Console.WriteLine("test"));
        var noAgree = new StyledStringElement("Whatever", () => Console.WriteLine("test"));


        var headerView = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 640, 85))
                              {
                                  Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/SafeWork_TandC_640_165.png")
                              };

        var section = new Section()
        {
            HeaderView = headerView
        };

      window.RootViewController = new DialogViewController(new RootElement("Login") {
               section,
               new Section()
                   {
                     webelement
                   },
                   new Section()
                       {
                          agree, noAgree
                       }
            });



        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        return true;
```

My question is - why are the dimensions for the WebView completely not related to the dimensions for the actual window? The header image has a width of 640px to make it the width of the iPhone yet the webview has a width of 300 to make it fit - 400 is way way too big for the screen and it actually goes off screen if set to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: retina.

Window dimensions are in non-retina pixels, to allow legacy app to work well. So, a 640px wide image will take 320px of screen unit if your device supports retina display.

Comment: To be fancy, these are called "points", not pixels.  Non-retina: 1px == 1pt, Retina: 2px == 1 pt.  This way you can always refer to things in points without regard for Retina or not.